# How to alternate iterations in multithreading a single function with python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python function that is pretty complex that im trying to run vs around 100 or so different NYSE symbols on the stock market. Right now it takes around 5 minutes to complete. This is not a terrible amount of time, but im trying to make it quicker by multithreading. My idea is that, since this is a single function, im just passing new parameters each iteration, it would maybe work to store a list of symbols that have "completed" then on a new iteration it just runs through the list and if a symbol doesnt exists in the list, it runs the computation. Heres some code i put together:

```
iteration_count = 0
for index, row in stocklist_df.iterrows():
    # The below just filters input data
    if '-' in row[0]:
        continue
    elif '.' in row[0]:
        continue
    elif '^' in row[0]:
        continue
    elif len(row[0]) > 4:
        continue
    else:
        symbol = row[0]
        #idea is that on first iteration it runs on first thread and appends to threadlist
        #second iteration looks at threadlist and if symbol exists, then skips and goes to the next

        threadlist.append([symbol, iteration_count])
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_info(symbol, 0))
        t1.start()

        if iteration_count > 1:
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_info(symbol, 0))
            t2.start()
```

Right now this doesnt appear to be working, and im not sure this is the best solution or maybe im implementing it wrong. How can i achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

I confess to having had some difficulty following your logic. I will just offer up that the usual method of handling threading when you have multiple, similar requests is to use thread pooling. There are several ways offered by Python, such as the `ThreadpoolExecutor` class `concurrent.futures` module (see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) for documentation). The following is an example. Here function `get_info` essentially just returns its argument:

```
import concurrent.futures


def get_info(symbol):
    return 'answer: ' + symbol


symbols = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
NUMBER_THREADS = min(30, len(symbols))

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_THREADS) as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_info, symbols)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

Prints:

```
answer: abc
answer: def
answer: ghi
answer: jkl
```

You can play around with the number of threads you create. If you are using for example, the `requests` package to retrieve URLs from the same website, then you might wish to create a `requests` `Session` object and pass that as an additional argument to `get_info`:

```
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import functools


def get_info(session, symbol):
    """
    r = session.get('https://somewebsite.com?symbol=' + symbol)
    return r.text
    """
    return 'symbol answer: ' + symbol


symbols = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
NUMBER_THREADS = min(30, len(symbols))

with requests.Session() as session:
    get_info_with_session = functools.partial(get_info, session) # this will be the first argument
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_THREADS) as executor:
        results = executor.map(get_info_with_session, symbols)
        for result in results:
            print(result)
```

Comment: this might be exactly what i was looking for. ill implement and get back with you later today as to the results. thank you for the detailed response. My only question is, if im looping through a list of around 100 symbols, will it prevent executing the same symbol twice?